# How to let buttons stay the same size on different screen(resolutions)

Tags: html, css

My site looks decent even at weird resolutions and on my phone, but the 4 download buttons that I have on there are acting weird. The text stays the same size and position but the button itself becomes a lot smaller when I make the window smaller; this is the css code for the button;

```
.btn {
  padding: .3em .8em;
  border: 1px solid #446d88;
  background: #fff linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.2), transparent);
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 .05em .25em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  border-radius: .2em;
  text-shadow: 0 -.05em .05em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  font-size: 125%;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

and this is the CSS for the text div;

```
.ptext3{
  font-family:"Lato", sans-serif;
  position:middle;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  color:#000;
  font-size:60%;
  letter-spacing:8px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

I've tried to google it but the answers I found described how to get buttons of the same size but I already have it, here are some screenshots of the problem:
good, wanted;

```
https://gyazo.com/f26e8668aba389ef1d3ab6daaf5e34d9
```

bad, same as on phone;

```
https://gyazo.com/14e9bad4f485b51e2cd713eb64f78d0e
```

Comment: Linked images do not display...

Comment: Can you share your html code too?

Comment: If you want the button to stay the same size .. Ues `px` in your CSS.  If you want your text to shrink WITH the button, use `em` or `vw` for the `font-size` property.  Percentages can get funky, because they might not be "listening" to the container you think they are

Comment: Also, make sure you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your head tag to prevent content from being smaller on small screens.

Comment: Did not know that about linked images, I'll keep it in mind for future posts. I had, for some reason, used an </i> tag, I have no idea why but removing that allowed me to change the size of my buttons individually, with  px instead of %. I already had the meta tag mentioned above.